# How to return distinct values for a field in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jhipster

I can retrieve the distinct values for a field using mongoDB query as,

```
db.context.distinct("context_name")
```

which results `["Restaurant", "School"]`

My Mongo collection name is `Context` and a document looks like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ca8a45cadee6167c4d92ba"),
    "_class" : "com.something.webappmongo.domain.Context",
    "context_name" : "Restaurant"
}
```

Now I want to get result using this query from Spring framework (Spring Boot 1.4.0). I was using Jhipster.

How to do it in repository interface and resource class?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Repository method "findDistinctBy[field]"

Comment: You need to be a lot more verbose than that. What did you try, what does your code look like, what's written in the logs? **Nobody** can help you based on "It didn't work".